# python sshclient hanging for the linux command

Tags: ssh, python, sshd

execution hanging for the second command and its works for simple linux commands like 'pwd', and 'ls' and so on, and any thought on this issue,

```
from paramiko import SSHClient
import paramiko, time, psutil

ssh_client = SSHClient()
ssh_client.load_system_host_keys()
ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh_client.connect(hsp_host_ip, port=22, username='xx-xxx',   password='xxxxxxxxxxxx')

stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_client.exec_command('pwd')
print(stdout.read())
print(stderr.read())

#execution hanging here and no response

stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_client.exec_command("sudo /usr/share/source/pyenv36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Gatewaydist/common_utils/btcli_bin/btcli /dev/ttyUSB0 h4 115200 -q")
print(stderr.read())
print(stdout.read())
print(stdin.read())
```

Comment: Perhaps `sudo` is waiting for interactive input (i.e. password)?

Comment: i found the problem as execution hanging at the stderr.read() where channel was not closed , similar to this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35266753/paramiko-python-module-hangs-at-stdout-read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the problem as execution hanging at the stderr.read()/read() where channel was not closed , similar to this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35266753/paramiko-python-module-hangs-at-stdout-read